# slowcheetah copys all reference dll's config file to target bin directory

Tags: c#, .net, dll, slowcheetah

I am new to SlowCheetah. Just installed it today as I need to add more config files to one of my console application to allow different settings for alpha test environment.

So I added a transform featured the name 'alpha' and the transformation is fine. But then I realised that when the project is build, all the referenced dlls' config files gets copied to my target directory.

I don't need that. I only need the config file for my exe. And also the dlls' config files contains sensitive information such as connection string which I intent to hide. I redefined connection strings in my exe's config so the dlls' config files are just unnecessary.

Is there a way to make sure those files do not get included when using SlowCheetah?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way after a couple of hours...

Add the following lines to the project .csproj file. Make it parallel to other PropertyGroup tags that are already there.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ScAllowCopyReferencedConfig Condition=" '$(ScAllowCopyReferencedConfig)'=='' ">false</ScAllowCopyReferencedConfig>
    <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions Condition=" '$(ScAllowCopyReferencedConfig)'=='true' ">
        $(AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions);
    </AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note the **false** in the second line does the trick.

The 3rd, 4th and 5th lines can be omitted. But if you keep those lines you can modify them to get rid of the intellisense xml files that will be copied to the output directory.